# How to use 2 variable for "for" statement in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, multimedia, video-editing

I want to use f and v for variable. f *.mkv and v *.mp3

```
for f in *.mkv v in *.mp3; do 
   ffmpeg -i "$f" -i "$v" -vcodec copy merge_"$f"
done
```

I dont know how to do it properly. I am still new with bash shell scripting.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Do the mkv and mp3 files have common names? Are you trying to pair up files?

Comment: Did you look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215088/bash-shell-script-two-variables-in-for-loop might be similar or duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `*.mp3` and `*.mkv` basenames are the same:

```
for f in *.mkv; do
    mp3name="${f%.mkv}.mp3"
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -i "$mp3name" -vcodec copy "merge_${f}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to loop through the variables the way it is expected to loop through with your original code, you can do this:

```
f=(*.mkv)
v=(*.mp3)
for((i=0;i<${#f[@]};i++));do
echo "${f[$i]} ${v[$i]}"
done
```

General assumption is, you have the same number of files for both `mkv` and `mp3`.

Or if the files have identical basenames, you can do this:

```
for f in *.mkv;do
v="${f/%mkv/mp3}"
echo "$f $v"
done
```

In `"${f/%mkv/mp3}"` `mkv` is being replaced by `mp3` at the end.

See [Bash Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for more info.